# Zend framework 3: Pass arguments to controllers

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework3

I'm trying to inject dependencies in a controller through controller factories.  My module.config.php file contains

```
<?php

namespace Commerce;

use Commerce\Controller\Plugin\Website;
use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'home' => [
                'type' => Literal::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
           'getFilters' => [
                'type' => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/api/getFilters',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\Api\SearchController::class,
                        'action' => 'getFilters'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
   'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
 Controller\Api\SearchController::class => function ($container) {
                return new Controller\Api\SearchController(
                 $container->get("first"),
                    $container->get("second")
                );
            },
            Controller\IndexController::class => function ($container) {
                return new Controller\IndexController();
            },
            Controller\Api\SearchController::class => InvokableFactory::class
        ]
        ]
// view_manager code
```

and controller file Controller\Api\SearchController contains

```
<?php

namespace Commerce\Controller\Api;
class SearchController extends \Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController
{

    public function __construct($a, $b)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
    }
    public function getFiltersAction()
    {
       // some code
    }
}
```

**Module.php** code

```
<?php

namespace Commerce;

use Base\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent; use Zend\Session\SessionManager;

class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface {
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }

    /**
     * This method is called once the MVC bootstrapping is complete.
     */
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $application = $event->getApplication();
        $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();

        // The following line instantiates the SessionManager and automatically
        // makes the SessionManager the 'default' one.
        $sessionManager = $serviceManager->get(SessionManager::class);
    } 
}
```

While running above code it says

> Too few arguments to function
>   Commerce\Controller\Api\SearchController::__construct(), 0 passed in
>   /var/www/html/zf3/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/Factory/InvokableFactory.php
>   on line 30 and exactly 2 expected

What I'm missing here ? What is the best way to inject parameter/value dependencies in controllers?

Comment: Looks like your controllers factories setting is ignored. Can you post the whole module.config.php? Also add Module.php code, just in case something is wrong there.

Comment: @JannesBotis I've updated code. Kindly check. Once I remove line  `Controller\Api\SearchController::class => InvokableFactory::class` it says _Unable to resolve service "first" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working . In module.config.php file instead of using

```
'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
 Controller\Api\SearchController::class => function ($container) {
                return new Controller\Api\SearchController(
                 $container->get("first"),
                    $container->get("second")
                );
            },
 ]
]
```

I had to use

```
'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
 Controller\Api\SearchController::class => function ($container) {
                return new Controller\Api\SearchController(
                "first",
                "second"
                );
            },
 ]
]
```